# NSFetchedResultsController group items with in a section

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am fetching the details of some products and grouping it under sections based on the main category.

Product object has two attributes mainCategory and subCategory.

I use feched results controller to group all products using mainCategory. Now with in the main category, there are products present from different subcategories. I want to group those products together, is it possible to group objects with in a section?

Below is what I am looking for, table will look like

```
MainCategory 1
---ProductA.Subcategory1
---ProductB.Subcategory1
---ProductC.Subcategory1
---ProductD.Subcategory2
---ProductE.Subcategory2
MainCategory 2
---ProductF.Subcategory1
---ProductG.Subcategory1
---ProductH.Subcategory1
---ProductI.Subcategory2
---ProductJ.Subcategory2
```

Is this achievable? Is there a way to use `setPropertiesToGroupBy` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with sort descriptors of `NSFetchRequest`.

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"mainCategory" ascending:YES],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"subCategory" ascending:YES],
];
```

Comment: Will that work? my sections are configured based on mainCategory. Section names are "mainCategory" and with in each section i need to group "subcategory". I shall try....